# Inner join in laravel using Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 model LeaveApplication and LeaveDetails model i would link to inner  join leave with leaveDetails model

> LeaveApplication Model

```
class LeaveApplication extends Model {

    public $table = 'leave_application';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'start_date', 'end_date'];
    public function leaveDetails() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\LeaveDetails", 'application_id');
    }
}
```

> This is LeaveDetails Model

```
class LeaveDetails extends Model {
    public $table = "leave_details";
    public $fillable = ['application_id','leave_date','leave_type'];
}
```

I try to access this using `LeaveApplication::with('leaveDetails')->where('leaveDetails.leave_date','2016-10-10')->get()`

It give me Error ,
This is not create inner join in eloquent.

I am also use `whereHas('leaveDetails')` and this not use inner join

Answer (score 1):

```
LeaveApplication::with('leaveDetails')->where('leaveDetails.leave_date','2016-10-10')->get()
```

It won't work, because Laravel queries use few joins. If you work on eager loading, i suggest using [constrained eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). Your Eloquent query will be looked like:

```
LeaveApplication::with(['leaveDetails' => function($query){
                                           $query->where('leave_date', '2016-10-10');
                                          }]);
```

If you're wondering what kind of query will be generated by Eloquent, try to dump it using [toSql()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1579).

Comment: it give all LeaveApplication data, it not checking data.

Comment: well, so actually you wish to retrieve `LeaveApplication` that has `LeaveDetails` that `leave_date` is `'2016-10-10'`? i thought you wish to get `LeaveApplication` **along with** it's `LeaveDetails` that have `leave_date` specified..

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman What is it that you want to achieve exactly? What is your query aiming to accomplish? Please give a clear idea as to what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to do this Query  `SELECT * FROM employee_leave_application INNER JOIN leave_details ON leave_details.application_id = employee_leave_application.id WHERE leave_details.leave_date = "2016-10-10" ` using Eloquent .

Comment: so, what information do you intend to get..? cause my query above will do just like your query but with two `select`s instead. one will be `SELECT * FROM employee_leave_application` followed by `SELECT * FROM leave_details WHERE leave_date = "2016-10-10"` and relation mappings done in memory by Laravel. So, you could get your leave details by something like `$leaveApplications->first()->leaveDetails->first()->leave_date` -- its a nested `Collection`.